# Duplicate records error although I'm using REPLACE INTO

Tags: mysql

Every night we're doing

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$path' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE $table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
($fields)
```

Records in the file located in $path will have some duplicate records as per the key in $table and that's why we are doing REPLACE INTO rather than INSERT INTO.

This strategy has been working errorlessly for years until last night something hiccuped, and the following error was to be found in the logs:

mySQL error occured: Duplicate key for record at 225811872 against record at 88773156 Guilty query: ALTER TABLE remp ENABLE KEYS.

If that matters, the table has probably grown to a bit beyond 200m rows (of 14.9 GiB) for the first time ever. Also, the table is partitioned into ~40 partitions.

From this moment on, any further SELECT statements on the table in question resulted in:

mySQL error occured: Table './azuondb/remp#P#p1' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed

A simple (manual!) REPAIR TABLE helped, but until I executed this, the table was 'in use' and inaccessible, thus seriously affecting the services we provide.

Anybody has an idea what has caused this error and how to help prevent it in the future?

Answer (score 1):

It happens from time to time to a MyISAM table to crash when performing multiple operations at the same time. In most cases a simple repair will do the trick, but if the table keeps doing this - you should identify what is the source of the problem.

Please refer to the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/corrupted-myisam-tables.html) and also this [similar question at dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15075/why-do-mysql-tables-crash-how-do-i-prevent-it).

Answer (score 0):

You should add a unique constraint to that field that is duplicating.

This should prevent the error. You can use UPDATE ON DUPLICATE as well.

The only thing is sometimes db can lock if you inserts and update on the same table.